# getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } while trying to remove table row dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked for the same problem in other threads but could not find the solution.
I am trying to clone a table row and append it to same table by changing the index of input field and I am also removing the add glyph-icon and replacing it with new glyph-icon which has `onClick` function and when I try to remove the row on click of the glyph-icon I am getting this(**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**) error. I checked my code again and again but could not find the solution.
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        var glyphRemove="";

            glyphRemove="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyph_size' id='remove' onClick='$(this).closest('tr').remove()'  aria-hidden='true'></span>";
                $("#add").click(function() {            

                    var clone= $("#cloneObject").clone();                       
                    clone.removeClass('hide');              
                    clone.prop('disabled',false); 
                    clone.find('#add').remove();
                    clone.find('#glyph').append(glyphRemove);                       
                    clone.appendTo("#shiftsTable");     



                    });
    });
```

how ever when I change the `onClick` function as `onClick=$this.parent().parent().remove()`, it works perfectly fine and remove the `td` section containing the glyph-icon.
Where am I getting wrong.

Comment: You have extra `}` after line `clone.appendTo("#shiftsTable");`

Comment: The { after clone.appentTo("#shiftsTable"); is redundant.

Comment: You're also going to have trouble with `onClick='$(this).closest('tr').remove()'`, look closely at those quotes.

Comment: i am sorry but I edited my code before posting that } after clone.appendto("#shiftsTable") is not extra.

Comment: I dint get it can you please explain

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
glyphRemove="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyph_size' id='remove' onClick='$(this).closest('tr').remove()'  aria-hidden='true'></span>";
                $("#add").click(function() {            

                    var clone= $("#cloneObject").clone();                       
                    clone.removeClass('hide');              
                    clone.prop('disabled',false); 
                    clone.find('#add').remove();
                    clone.find('#glyph').append(glyphRemove);                       
                    clone.appendTo("#shiftsTable");     
                }
                ^


                    });
```

Remove it.

Comment: that } is not extra I have some logic before appending and I am using this logic, however I removed unwanted code from my question and this } was left by mistake. I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var glyphRemove="";
     glyphRemove="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyph_size' id='remove' onClick='$(this).closest('tr').remove()'  aria-hidden='true'></span>";
     $("#add").click(function() {            
         var clone= $("#cloneObject").clone();                       
         clone.removeClass('hide');              
         clone.prop('disabled',false); 
         clone.find('#add').remove();
         clone.find('#glyph').append(glyphRemove);                       
         clone.appendTo("#shiftsTable");     
     });
});
```

Comment: what is diffrent here?